# How to replace more than a space in a string with some special character in c#

Tags: c#, replace

How to replace more than a space in a string with some special character in c#?

I have a string as

```
Hi I  am new  here. Would   you    please help    me?
```

I want output as

```
Hi I$am new$here. Would$you$please help$me?
```

I tried

```
string line=@"Hi I  am new  here. Would   you    please help    me?";
string line1 = Regex.Replace(line,@"[\s\s]+","$");
Console.WriteLine(line1);
```

but I am getting output as

```
Hi$I$am$new$here.$Would$you$please$help$me?
```

Could you please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You should specify than you want more than two (`{2,}`) whitespace characters (`\s`):

```
string line1 = Regex.Replace(line,@"\s{2,}","$");
```

or only more than two spaces (`[ ]`):

```
string line1 = Regex.Replace(line,@"[ ]{2,}","$");
```

*Note*: `[\s\s]+` means: one or more of character group specified in `[]`, so as `\s` is doubled, it simply means: one or more of whitespace character.

Answer (score 2):

You were not far from the correct solution. The simplest fix for your code is:

```
string line1 = Regex.Replace(line,@"\s\s+","$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression

```
[\s]{2,}
```

which goes in the code as:

```
string line1 = Regex.Replace(line,@"[\s]{2,}","$");
```

[Here is a rubular showing this](http://rubular.com/r/A3wgvF0u4a)